# MySQL custom ORDER BY when there is GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

i want to know how to use a custom ORDER BY when i am using a group by before.

This is my query

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN a.edad < 40 THEN 'Menos de 40'
     WHEN a.edad >= 40 AND a.edad <=49 THEN 'De 40 a 49'
     WHEN a.edad >= 50 AND a.edad <=59 THEN 'De 50 a 59'
     WHEN a.edad >= 60 AND a.edad <=69 THEN 'De 60 a 69'
     WHEN a.edad >=70 THEN 'De 70 y más'
      ELSE(SELECT a.edad) END AS 'Grupo de edad',
      SUM(IF(a.sexo='F',1,0)) AS Mujeres,SUM(IF(a.sexo='M',1,0)) AS Hombres
FROM academicos a
WHERE CCN REGEXP 'I|D65' /*Tomando en cuenta a la persona docente*/
GROUP BY 1
```

These are the results:

```
Grupo de edad, Mujeres, Hombres
'De 40 a 49', 7, 3
'De 50 a 59', 8, 5
'De 60 a 69', 20, 25
'De 70 y más', 6, 10
'Menos de 40', 2, 0
```

I want the text `'Menos de 40', 2, 0` to appear at the top.
How do i achieve this?

Comment: What is the criteria you are mentally applying which should cause that record to be at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to duplicate the `CASE` statement to your `ORDER BY` clause with slightly different return criteria.  I translated your query to English as best I could, I mean no disrespect.

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN age < 40 THEN 'Less than 40'
       WHEN age >= 40 AND age <= 49 THEN 'From 40 to 49'
       WHEN age >= 50 AND age <= 59 THEN 'From 50 to 59'
       WHEN age >= 60 AND age <= 69 THEN 'From 60 to 69'
       ELSE age END AS 'Age Grouping',
  SUM(IF(sex = 'F', 1, 0)) AS 'Girls',
  SUM(IF(sex = 'M', 1, 0)) AS 'Boys'
FROM students
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN age < 40 THEN 1
       WHEN age >= 40 AND age <= 49 THEN 2
       WHEN age >= 50 AND age <= 59 THEN 3
       WHEN age >= 60 AND age <= 69 THEN 4
       ELSE 5 END
```

**Results:**

```
+---------------+-------+------+
| Age Grouping  | Girls | Boys |
+---------------+-------+------+
| Less than 40  |     1 |    2 |
| From 40 to 49 |     0 |    1 |
| From 50 to 59 |     0 |    1 |
| From 60 to 69 |     0 |    1 |
+---------------+-------+------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bac65/2)

Comment: That did the trick! BTW, thanks for translating the query into English.